# Naming a JSON Array in Django REST API

Tags: python, json, django, rest

I've seen some of the similar questions on this subject, but the structure of other posters' code is different than the tutorial I followed for building the REST api (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/). Following the tutorial, I get an unnamed JSON response when querying the API. I have `serializers.py` and `views.py` as the two files that process the JSON:

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from main.models import Request

class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ('user', 'request', 'time')
```

views.py

```
class RequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Request.objects.all().order_by('-time')
    serializer_class = RequestSerializer
    paginate_by = None
```

Other solutions have been along the lines of adding `return Response({"data": serializer.data})`, but I'm unsure where I could add this in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     results_field = "your selected name"
```

or you can override the `list` method

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object_list = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object_list, many=True)
    return Response({'results': serializer.data})
```

Comment: Thank you @Exprator. The second method worked for me.